# How to optionally add a compiler plugin in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-3

I have a project which depends on https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector and is currently cross-compiled against scala 2.12 and 2.13, and I want to add support for scala 3.0. However, kind-projector is not available on scala 3.0 since the syntax it enables is part of the native scala 3 syntax.

Before, I used this setting to add the compiler plugin:

```scala
addCompilerPlugin("org.typelevel" % "kind-projector" % "0.11.3" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

Now, I'm trying to disable that setting if the `scalaVersion` is 3.0.0.

The closest I've got is

```scala
Def.setting {
    scalaVersion.value match {
        case "3.0.0" => new Def.SettingList(Nil)
        case _ => Seq(
            addCompilerPlugin("org.typelevel" % "kind-projector" % "0.11.3" cross CrossVersion.full)
        )
    }
}
```

but the types don't work out (that's an `Initialize` but it needs to be a `Setting`).

How can I conditionally disable the compiler plugin based on the scala version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addCompilerPlugin` is a shortcut for `libraryDependencies += compilerPlugin(dependency)`

Thus, it should work with something like this

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= {
  scalaVersion.value match {
    case "3.0.0" =>
      Nil
    case _ =>
      List(compilerPlugin("org.typelevel" % "kind-projector" % "0.11.3" cross CrossVersion.full))
  }
}
```

*There might be a better way to do it though.*

---

Original answer which doesn't work because `scalaVersion.value` is not available in this context:

```scala
scalaVersion.value match {
  case "3.0.0" =>
    new Def.SettingList(Nil)
  case _ => 
    addCompilerPlugin("org.typelevel" % "kind-projector" % "0.11.3" cross CrossVersion.full)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The `value` method is a macro that I think only works in certain contexts, i.e. after a `:=` operator, or inside one of the `Def` methods.

Comment: @Dylan Indeed, I updated my answer with something that should work better

Comment: Ah that looks promising. I'll be able to check that once I get off work